# Lua set table elements in table function

Tags: lua, scope, lua-table

Here is the snippet:

```
    local t = {}

    t.tt = {}

    function t.xx()
        for i=1,10 do
            t.tt[i] = i
        end
    end


    for i=1,10 do
        print(t.tt[i])
    end
```

Result of `print` function is all `nil`.Why all elements in `t.tt` is nil ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to actually run the function before printing:

```
local t = {}

t.tt = {}

function t.xx()
    for i=1,10 do
        t.tt[i] = i
    end
end

-- execute function here
t.xx()

for i=1,10 do
    print(t.tt[i])
end
```

or just assign the values:

```
local t = {}

t.tt = {}

-- no function here
for i=1,10 do
    t.tt[i] = i
end

for i=1,10 do
    print(t.tt[i])
end
```